# JQM versions 1.0rc shrinks website in mobile safari

Tags: jquery-mobile, version

I am a beginner to jQuery Mobile and am developing a mobile website within Dreamweaver CS5.5. Once I received the new DW I immediately updated to jqm 1.0a4.1. Designed my site and it looks good on desktop Safari and mobile Safari. Then I updated to jqm 1.0rc1 and while the site looks same on desktop safari, the entire website design decreased to an unreadable size in mobile safari. I tried again with 1.0rc2 and same thing happened as with 1.0rc1. When I return to 1.0a4.1 the site looks great on desktop and mobile.

Does anyone know why this would happen: is there something I'm missing and can correct to have the latest version of jqm work on both desktop and mobile safari?

Thanks for your time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery Mobile 1.0a4.1 dynamically injects a viewport tag into the DOM. In newer versions you need to do this yourself. Try adding this viewport tag to the `<head>` of your documents:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" >
```

Comment: Perfection! Thanks for the quick response and for not only giving me the code but also the reason why. Appreciate this so much.